# Program requires .net5 SDK, why?

Tags: wpf, frameworks, .net-5

A few days ago I updated a wpf program from **.net4.8** to **.net5**. Some users now get an error message that can be seen in the picture.

[image]

These users have **.NET Desktop Runtime 5.0.x** installed. Apparently that is not enough. The program will not work until the **SDK** is installed.

My question now is, is there any way I can quickly tell whether I'm using classes or methods that need an SDK?
Do I have to adjust the publish config?

I would not like to deliver the whole framework with the program together.

Comment: Looks like you must also install  the ASP.NET runtime. You shuold create an installer that checks if the runtime environment is valid and asks the user to install it otherwise.

Comment: [ASP.NET Core Runtime 5.0.9](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0)

Comment: Aspnetcore is web. They have desktop runtime installed, you say. Desktop != Web.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, but where can i see which part of the tool need this framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appearantly your app has a dependency on the **ASP.NET** runtime as well.

You will either have to download and install this one separately or remove any references to it from your app.

Check for any framework reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` in your project files (`Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`) or under Dependencies->Frameworks in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you, I have now removed the reference. In fact, it wasn't used.